# Is there a standard way for a REST API to request that 201 Created includes a body?

Tags: rest, http

When designing an HTTP REST API, is there a standard way to request full entity bodies in `201 Created` responses? I remember reading about it some time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: API can support `Prefer` request header to achieve this.

`Prefer: return=representation` requests a full response (e.g. entity body).
`Prefer: return=minimal` requests a minimal response (e.g. headers only).

This header is defined in [RFC 7240](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) (Prefer Header for HTTP).